# Даты в Highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, дата, график, highcharts

Даты и значения хранятся в БД. Достаю их оттуда и делаю следующее в php (ajax)

```
for ($t=0; $t<$kolvo_project[$z];$t++){
        array_push($array_dates, $projects[$t]['time_in']);
        //сформируем параметры для вывода графика дата/занчение
        if ($t+1<$kolvo_project[$z]){
            $text = $text."[{$projects[$t]['time_in']}, {$projects[$t]['project_idproject']}], ";
        } else {
            $text = $text."[{$projects[$t]['time_in']}, {$projects[$t]['project_idproject']}]";
        }

    }
```

Затем делаю следующее в строке js

```
for (i=0; i<otvet.line.length;i++){
                series.push({name:otvet.line[i], data: '['+otvet.text+']' , color: colors[i]});
            }
```

otvet.text - это $text из ajax и содержит
[2016-09-01, 87], [2016-09-02, 87], [2016-08-01, 8], [2016-08-02, 8]

Но график получается такой:
[image: График]

Выручайте, как отобразить значение на оси Y в соответствии с датой на X

```
xAxis: { type: 'datetime',

                        categories: otvet.arrayOfDates,
                        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                        title: {enabled: false},

                },
```

**//-----------------------------РЕШЕНИЕ--------------------------------------**

Решил вопрос просто. Поставил библиотеку moment.js для работы с датами. Собрал дату и значение в персональный массив [дата_1, значение1],[дата_2, значение_2] и тд., а в JS прописал

```
for (var i=0; i<otvet.kolvo_project[z]; i++){
                    //распарсим массив дат и значений
                    otvet.arr_itog[z][i][0] = moment(otvet.arr_itog[z][i][0]).valueOf();
                    otvet.arr_itog[z][i][1] = JSON.parse(otvet.arr_itog[z][i][1]);
               }
                series.push({name:otvet.line[i], data: otvet.arr_itog[z], color: colors[i]});
```

**Помогла статья: [ссылка](http://blog.emilecantin.com/web/highcharts/2014/10/26/highcharts-datetime-series.html)**

Comment: Частично нужный результат получил Сделал даты в кавычках, text обернул в [ ] в php, а не в JS и сам текст распарсл в JS - JSON.parse (otvet.text). Убрал categories: otvet.arrayOfDates. Теперь график выводится, но не выводятся даты по Y (одни нули). Как быть с форматом дат в подписи?

Comment: ... Если оставляю подписи в categories, то значения все равно не совпадают с датами.

Comment: Решил вопрос просто. Поставил библиотеку moment.js для работы с датами. Собрал дату и значение в персональный массив [дата_1, значение1],[дата_2, значение_2] и тд., а в JS прописал for (var i=0; i<otvet.kolvo_project[z]; i++){
                        //распарсим массив дат и значений
                        otvet.arr_itog[z][i][0] = moment(otvet.arr_itog[z][i][0]).valueOf();
                        otvet.arr_itog[z][i][1] = JSON.parse(otvet.arr_itog[z][i][1]);
                   }
                    series.push({name:otvet.line[i], data: otvet.arr_itog[z], color: colors[i]});